# Source code for saving drawn view to image

Tags: java, android, image, save, android-canvas

I have aplication where I drawing object by canvas. And I want saving this pictures like image. For example bmp, or jpg to folder. How can I do it ? Here is bite of my code.

```
public class hell extends View{


public static int width= aktivita.width;    
public static int koeficient = 5;

final Paint mPaint;

public static int t;
public boolean filter = true;
static ArrayList<Circle> mCircles;


private static boolean Kontroler = true;





public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

     Paint p = new Paint();

     p.setColor(Color.RED);


            kres(canvas);


            invalidate();
        }
    }




public krouzky(Context context, AttributeSet atrs) {
    super(context, atrs);

    mMalovani = new Paint();
    mMalovani.setColor(Color.RED);
    mMalovani.setAntiAlias(true);

        createCircles();

}
```

Adding objects for draw

```
public static void Prid() {

     int ran = aktivita.width/8;

    mCircles.add(new Circle(80, 200, ran));

}
```

Make arrayList

```
private static void createCircles() { if (mCircles == null) { mCircles = new ArrayList<Circle>(); }

 int r = aktivita.width/8;
mCircles.add(new Circle(80, 200, r));

}
```

Drawing object
        private void kres(Canvas canvas) {

```
        for (Circle c : mCircles) {
            // 
            canvas.drawCircle(c.getCurrentX(), c.getCurrentY(), c.getRadius(),
                    mPaint);


        }
        }
```

I tried this, but after start with button click    loadBitmapFromView(v);
                                        save();
my program shut down, and in SD card is file with .png suffix. But It have 0 bites, and I´t open it.

```
 public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View view) {

        // width measure spec 
        int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                view.getMeasuredWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        // height measure spec 
        int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                view.getMeasuredHeight(), View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        // measure the view 
        view.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
        // set the layout sizes 
        view.layout(view.getLeft(), view.getTop(), view.getMeasuredWidth() + view.getLeft(), view.getMeasuredHeight() + view.getTop());
        // create the bitmap
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        // create a canvas used to get the view's image and draw it on the bitmap 
        Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
        // position the image inside the canvas 
        c.translate(-view.getScrollX(), -view.getScrollY());
        // get the canvas
        view.draw(c);

        return bitmap;
}

    public void save(){
 String fileName = String.valueOf(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
// generate the image path 
String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator +  fileName + ".png";

 try {

     // save the image as png 
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
    View view = null;
    // compress the image to png and pass it to the output stream 
    loadBitmapFromView(view).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);

   // save the image 
   out.flush();
   out.close();

} catch (Exception error) {
      Log.e("Error saving image", error.getMessage());
}

    }
```

Comment: Show us what you have done so far, please.

Comment: So there it is. I would like to have method for saving drawn objects like bmp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a bitmap from a View:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    Drawable bgDrawable =view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable!=null) 
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else 
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return returnedBitmap;
}
```

To save it to SD Card:

```
public void saveImage(Bitmap b)
{
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    OutputStream fOut = null;

    File file = new File(path, "XXXXXXXXXXX.jpg");
    fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
    fOut.flush();
    fOut.close();
    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName());
}
```

You can do just the insert in MediaStore, but it will loose quality. This way the compression is done with the quality you want.

**EDIT:**

Added some logging to help figure out why you're getting the FileNotFound exception:

```
public void saveImage(Bitmap b)
{
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    OutputStream fOut = null;

    File file = new File(path, "XXXXXXXXXXX.jpg");
    Log.d("saveImage", "File to save: " + file.getAbsolutePath());

    try {
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("saveImage", "Couldn't open file: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    if(fOut != null) {
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks great, thank you. But I have problem with this line: MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName()); I don´t know what should I import or declare.

Comment: FileNotFoundException

Comment: FileNotFoundException for: MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),‌​file.getName(),file.getName());

Comment: It should be some problem with the file path. Add some logs to check the results file and fOut and post the logcat here please. I'll edit the function for you in my reply.

Comment: Now I have error on this line: Log.d("saveImage", "Couldn't open file: ", e.getMessage());

And Descript information is:"
Method D (String, String, Throwable) in the Log type not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String)" 
So if I fix to: "Log.d("saveImage", "Couldn't open file: ");" I get it:"Untreated type of exception IOException" for last three lines of code (without "{")

Comment: Sorry, typo error my fault... It should be a '+' instead of ',' before e.getMessage()